# Exception: Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am using file picker from below link: 2.0.8-beta 
https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

I have setup my iOS xamarin project and sets all the data in my application mentioned in below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/intro-to-cloudkit

But now I am getting below error for iOS. Any body have any idea?
Exception:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application initializing
>   document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is
>   com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?
>
> Native stack trace:
>
> 0 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185ace37c + 148
>          1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000184d14528 objc_exception_throw + 56
>          2 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185ace238 + 0
>          3 Foundation 0x00000001864697f4 + 112
>          4 UIKit 0x000000018f77ff0c + 300
>          5 UIKit 0x000000018f77f788 + 228
>          6 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS 0x0000000102e038e8 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS +    38582504
>          7 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS 0x0000000102245904 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS +    26269956
>          8 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS 0x000000010321dfd0 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS +    42885072
>          9 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS 0x000000010321f4e4 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS +    42890468
>          10 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS 0x000000010322f334 XamarinFilePickerTest.iOS +    42955572

Answer (score 2):

> Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?

Refer to [Enabling CloudKit in a Xamarin Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/intro-to-cloudkit#enabling-cloudkit-in-a-xamarin-application)

Enable `iCloud` in `Entitlements.plist`and ensure the Ubiquity Container exists for the application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. We also need to enable iCloud from  apple site.